# How to disable a button with JS?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a site with products. I want to disable the "Add to Cart" button.

If I inspect my page and manually enter "disabled", it works.

How to disable the button with JS ?

Here is my page :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znr2X.png)

And a JS file that I created in my theme :

```
(function ($) {


})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Did you even search? A google search for "javascript disable button" gives you the stackoverlfow question linked as a dupe.

Comment: `$("#you-button").prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: @kiranvj perfect thank you